# ELF section padding

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, sections, toolchain

I may be too curious or careful, but please consider this:
If I place for example an array to some section
`char buff[128] __attribute__((my_section))`;
and then using linker script place that section for example at address 0x10004000,
can I be always sure, that `&buff[0]` will always be 0x10004000? (I am considering ARMCC (former RealView) by ARM Inc. as well as basic GCC toolchain and GNU ARM opensource.) May there be `buff` offset or padding from beginning  or may some service (runtime, linking, tollchain specific) stuff could be placed there at 0x10004000 before `buff`?
Also, are there any differences between C and C++ in this situation? Because C++ has "more stuff to do in background". :)
I you could provide any kind of documentation for this as well as your knowledge — much of appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, &buff[0] will always be 0x10004000. You could see section 9.46 in "Compiler user guide" book of Keil help file.

Char array is the inline objects of c/c++. So the compiler do the same thing for c/c++.

Comment: Well it's not completely correct. If you have multiple objects in this section the order in which they are laid out in memory is not guaranteed, so you may need to specifically set the addresses in the linker script. But of course if you reserved this section to only store this buffer then you are good to go.

Comment: @ChristopheAugier Yes. If there are many objects in the same section, it's best to dedicate the object address explicitly.

Comment: I think this is not always true for subsections. If you make a `.eeprom.my` section, and specify from the linker script that that section is 100 bytes after the beginning of the `.eeprom` section, the linker may decide to place `.eeprom.my` at the beginning of `.eeprom` if nothing uses those 100 bytes.